# Should send() and recv() buffer size be as big as possible?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, http, winsock

I'm sending a .mp3 file (.jpg and other extensions as well, size between 1K to 50MB) using winsock over http. The client sends file and the server receives the file .
I have serveral questions:

1. Should send() buffer size and recv() buffer size be the same?
2. What size should I choose, fixed size or a size big enough to contain all data?

Here comes the code.

Client:

```
... //POST /index.html HTTP/1.1 and so on

sprintf_s(header, "%sContent-Length: %d\r\n", header, sizeof(szFileData ));
sprintf_s(header, "%s%s\r\n", header , szFileData );  

... //Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"submit\" and so on

while(send(sock,  header, strlen(header), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Server：

```
recv(sock, recvbuf , 4096 , 0);  //neither strlen(recvbuf) nor 4096 works
...//extract file name, content and so on

FILE *pFile;
pFile = fopen ( filename , "wb" );
if ( fwrite(filedata, sizeof(filedata), 1,  pfile) != 1)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Failed!", "MSG", MB_OK);
}
```

I get a result that either is empty or loses some content.

Comment: Warning: Don't use the same buffer as both source and destination in `sprintf` (or its variants), that's undefined behavior.

Comment: buffer size does not matter, you can read in a while loop.

Comment: Also, don't call `send` in a loop while it's failing, you might end up with an infinite loop. Check the result of `recv` to see if everything's okay, and also get the *actual* size of the data received.

Comment: Lastly, you receive into `recvbuf`, I assume it's an *array* of 4096 characters? Then what is `filedata`?

Comment: There are some slight optimizations. You want to set the size that will work efficiently with your hardware MTU (less a few bytes reserved for packet headers, etc.) In the past there were formulas for computing these approximations in the dial-up world, they may have been relegated to the way of the dinosaur by now..

Comment: What is this `sizeof(filedata, 1,  pfile)`?

Comment: "*you can read in a while loop.*" one **has to** read/receive in a loop, as `recv()` might very well return few bytes (up to one byte only) as it was told to. Read the documentation closely, including the "RETURNS" section.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You said a lot of "Don't". I'm so NOT sure what to do. Can you write the right example for me please?

Comment: @alk It's a typo, ignore it plz. It should be fwrite(filedata, sizeof(filedata), 1,  pfile)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  Here is recvbuf: `char recvbuf[buf_size] = {'\0'};` But the size of `recvbuf`  troubles me too. Should I set `buf_size` as big as possible like `40960` or  just the same size as `recv()` like `4096` ?  `filedata` is what should be written in .mp3 file. `filedata` is not the same as `recvbuf` ( coz `recvbuf` contains `POST /index.html HTTP/1.1` and so on. )

Comment: Like others said, it's really no use in using such large buffers, or sending such large buffers, as it will be broken down into smaller packages anyway. For starters you should try not to overflow the buffers in the operating system, then the standard [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) on ethernet is less than 1500 bytes, and if the receiving end can't receive as fast as you expect then you will fill up the receivers OS buffers as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems.

1) send() doesn't necessarily send everything.  There are situations where it might only send some of what you give it.  So be prepared for that.

2) recv() returns the number of bytes actually read or -1 on error.  You should copy the those bytes from the recvbuf.  Also check the return value.  If it's -1 then there was an error and you need to use errno to find out what the error is.

To ensure everything is sent use sendall (from [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html)):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int sendall(SOCKET s, char *buf, int *len)
{
    int total = 0;        // how many bytes we've sent
    int bytesleft = *len; // how many we have left to send
    int n;

    while(total < *len) {
        n = send(s, buf+total, bytesleft, 0);
        if (n == -1) { break; }
        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
    }

    *len = total; // return number actually sent here

    return n==-1?-1:0; // return -1 on failure, 0 on success
}
```

For receiving something like:

```
int nbytes = 0;
while ((nbytes = recv(sock, recvbuf , 4096 , 0)) > 0){
    // From here, valid bytes are from recvbuf to recvbuf + nbytes.
    // You could simply fwrite(fp, recvbuf, nbytes) or similar. 
}
```

Make sure you don't get confused between application buffers and socket buffers.  They are different things.  The socket buffers are in kernel space.  App buffers are what you're using here.  There is potentially an optimal size but it various depending on what you're doing.  Making them 4K is usually reasonable.

If anything isn't clear, consult Beej's guide.  This is all very simple but in a real app I'd tend to use non-blocking sockets and/or epoll if on Linux.

Comment: Just realised you've tagged windows.  Nevertheless these concepts still apply.  Instead of errno you'd check WSAGetLastError() for example.

Comment: sendall takes a pointer to an int, the number of bytes returned.  You might need to do a little bit of tweaking to make it work under windows as the typenames might be different.  SOCKET is int under Linux.  I changed that for you... not sure if it's quite perfect but you get the idea. 

Have a read of Beej's guide too.  He does talk about windows too.